# CDK ClientVpnEndpoint. Would like to understand to get DnsName of created VpnEndpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm creating `ClientVpnEndpoint` using `@aws-cdk/aws-ec2`

```
 const clientVpnEndpoint = new ClientVpnEndpoint(stack, "vpn-enpoint", {
    vpc: vpc,
    cidr: "10.16.0.0/22",
    clientCertificateArn: config.clientCertificateArn,
    serverCertificateArn: config.serverCertificateArn,
    dnsServers: ["8.8.8.8", "4.4.4.4"],
    logging: false,
  })
```

I would like to read property DnsName that I see in console in summary section, I as well can see it when I run cli command `aws ec2 describe-client-vpn-endpoints`.

My best attempt, that doesn't work:

```
  const cfnVpnEndpoint = vpnEndpoint.node.defaultChild as CfnClientVpnEndpoint;

  new CfnOutput(stack, "vpn-enpoint-output", {
    value: cfnVpnEndpoint.getAtt("DnsName").toString(),
  });
```

I'm getting error:

```
.../Value/Fn::GetAtt: Resource type AWS::EC2::ClientVpnEndpoint does not support attribute {DnsName}
```

I actually cannot make `getAtt`, to work for me with any other props. How to use it?

Could you help me to find out to reach read props of DnsName of ClientVpnEndpoint

Answer (score 2):

The CDK/CloudFormation simply doesn't support this attribute for the ClientVPNEndpoint. It can neither be found in the [CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.ClientVpnEndpoint.html) nor in the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-clientvpnendpoint.html). If you really need this value as the output of the stack, you should have a look at using a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).